# Ring Embeds in Monoid Ring

Tags: ring-theory, proof-writing, monoid

Let $(S,+)$ be a nontrivial commutative monoid and $R$ be a ring.

Prove that $R$ embeds in $R[X;S]$ via $a \to aX^0$

I'm not exactly sure how to approach this... I think I may need to use the fact that $R \subseteq R[X;S]$

Is that fact obvious because a monoid ring is constructed from a ring and a monoid so $R[X;S]$ is constructed by the ring $R$ and monoid $S$? 
How can I use that fact in the proof though?

Comment: What do you mean by $R[X; S]$?

Comment: It's the monoid ring of S over R.